# how long it takes you to learn backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, duration

I just decide to learn backbone.js. I am a between junior and intermediate level front-end developer. my current job is dealing with html, css and jQuery. My boss asked me to learn this backbone.js and want to know how long it gonna take me to learn. so can anyone who experienced before tell me how long it gonna take?

thank you

Comment: It took me a couple of hours to go through the source code of the [Todos app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) and figure it out. You could do it over the weekend.

Comment: Coming from a jQuery background, it took me nearly a month to master it. Here's a good set of tutorials I used - http://hackr.io/tutorials/backbone-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know javascript, it will take awhile. I know this because I didn't really understand javascript when I got started with it. By know javascript, I mean being able to understand and fully explain:

- [Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)
- Object.prototype
- .call, .apply, and .bind
- Closures/Lexical Scope
- Anonymous functions
- Function Hoisting

If you don't know all that, get and read Crockford's [Javascript: the Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

If you do know all that, then you need to understand how to use Backbone properly otherwise it won't make any sense. When using Backbone, you really shouldn't have any non-backbone javascript outside of a sparse initialization of your base Views...also learning how to use the built in event binding is essential. [This](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals) is a pretty good guide, as (obviously) are all the sources [here](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials,-blog-posts-and-example-sites)

So I would say it could take a few days to a week or longer to fully comprehend whats going on, and much longer to get to the point of being very skilled with it.

Answer (score 3):

I only just started with backbone as well and i must say it's pretty straight forward.
So assuming that you already have a thorough understanding of JavaScript it self, i think you can get started with it within 2-3 days ( with the right amount of dedication that is ).
If you are not yet very familiar with JavaScript, you have to make sure you get that down first.

Code school has an excellent high quality interactive tutorial that will give you a rocket start. 
http://www.codeschool.com/

But there are plenty of free resources available as well, so don't let that stop you !
http://backbonetutorials.com/

The documentation on github is very complete, but it's probably not the best place to get started.
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

If you are looking in to backbone you might also want to look into AMD with requireJS, that is a little more complex but definitely worth looking into at as well !
http://requirejs.org/